# Cauchy sequence question.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is Cauchy.

All up until the * is my work, the rest is from the solution, of which i don't understand.

Let $m > n$, then

$|\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}| \le |\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}}| +|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}| < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$.

*

so if for a given $\epsilon$ > 0, we choose $N_1 \ge \frac{2}{\epsilon} $ then...

Is this because  $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a decreasing sequence for n? I just cant quite make the connection here, really cloudy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1.** Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}=0$ and every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence, $\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

**Solution 2.** We have
$$
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}}\right|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\rightarrow 0 \quad\text{as}\quad m,n\rightarrow\infty
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}}\right|=0.
$$

**Solution 3.** Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choosing $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
N_0>\frac{4}{(\varepsilon)^2}.
$$
Then for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\geq N_0, n\geq N_0$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_0}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_0}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}}\right|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: @HMPARTICLE : Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the choice of $N_1$...

You have already arrived at

$$ |\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}| \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}  $$

So given an $\epsilon \gt 0$ since there are arbitrarily large natural numbers, there is $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $ N_1  \gt \dfrac{ 4}{\epsilon^2} \iff  \epsilon \gt  \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{N_1}}$.

Now let $m, n$ be arbitrary natural numbers greater than $N_1$. Without loss of generality you may suppose that $m \ge n$ as well. Then,

$$ |\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}| \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \lt \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{N_1}} \lt \epsilon  $$

And that is why this is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I do not know why we can assume that $m>n$.

Comment: Actually it should be $m \ge n$ and this is because one of the two numbers is surely not less than the other. And if we wrote it the wrong way around we can just switch it and continue. $m, n$ are just two numbers. Which one is what is just not our problem.

Comment: I just got it, it was painfully simple, had a serious mental block, totally ashamed. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: No Issues. Anytime.

Comment: Please see Solution 3 in my answer.

Comment: We also cannot assume that $m\geq n$ or $n\geq m$. :D